# Figuring average queue when missing row mean 0 in queue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that keeps track of our phone queue system.  Any time the queue is one or higher it adds a number to this row of when it happened and when it ended.

However, it doesn't keep track (understandably so) of all the time when the queue was at zero.

I need to figure out a way to figure this out on the fly and return the average queue size for reporting figures.

Here is part of a days data can provide more if needed.  I tried to just do a straight average but this returned a higher than normal count because it doesn't take into account the times when the queue size was zero.

```
ID      GROUPID             STARTTIME           ENDTIME         QUEUESIZE   ts
363222  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:01:36    11/9/15 14:02:01    1   11/9/15 14:02:01
363223  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:02:19    11/9/15 14:02:58    1   11/9/15 14:02:59
363226  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:02:58    11/9/15 14:04:22    2   11/9/15 14:04:23
363227  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:04:22    11/9/15 14:04:48    3   11/9/15 14:04:49
363229  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:04:48    11/9/15 14:06:32    2   11/9/15 14:06:33
363230  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:06:32    11/9/15 14:07:18    1   11/9/15 14:07:19
363231  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:07:18    11/9/15 14:07:55    2   11/9/15 14:07:55
363232  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:07:55    11/9/15 14:09:01    1   11/9/15 14:09:02
363233  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:09:01    11/9/15 14:09:24    2   11/9/15 14:09:25
363234  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:09:24    11/9/15 14:09:46    1   11/9/15 14:09:47
363235  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:09:46    11/9/15 14:10:42    2   11/9/15 14:10:42
363236  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:10:42    11/9/15 14:10:45    3   11/9/15 14:10:47
363237  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:10:45    11/9/15 14:11:06    4   11/9/15 14:11:08
363238  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:11:06    11/9/15 14:11:58    5   11/9/15 14:11:59
363239  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:11:58    11/9/15 14:12:02    4   11/9/15 14:12:04
363240  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:12:02    11/9/15 14:12:45    3   11/9/15 14:12:47
363241  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:12:45    11/9/15 14:13:21    2   11/9/15 14:13:23
363242  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:13:21    11/9/15 14:14:45    1   11/9/15 14:14:45
363243  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:14:45    11/9/15 14:15:31    2   11/9/15 14:15:31
363245  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:15:31    11/9/15 14:17:14    3   11/9/15 14:17:15
363246  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:17:14    11/9/15 14:17:17    2   11/9/15 14:17:18
363247  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:17:17    11/9/15 14:17:39    3   11/9/15 14:17:40
363248  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:17:39    11/9/15 14:17:59    4   11/9/15 14:18:00
363249  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:17:59    11/9/15 14:18:18    3   11/9/15 14:18:18
363252  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:18:18    11/9/15 14:21:37    4   11/9/15 14:21:38
363253  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:21:37    11/9/15 14:21:50    3   11/9/15 14:21:52
363254  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:21:50    11/9/15 14:24:04    2   11/9/15 14:24:04
363255  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:24:04    11/9/15 14:25:09    1   11/9/15 14:25:10
363256  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:25:09    11/9/15 14:25:13    2   11/9/15 14:25:14
363258  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:25:13    11/9/15 14:26:20    3   11/9/15 14:26:22
363259  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:26:20    11/9/15 14:27:07    4   11/9/15 14:27:08
363260  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:27:07    11/9/15 14:28:44    3   11/9/15 14:28:45
363261  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:28:44    11/9/15 14:30:26    2   11/9/15 14:30:27
363262  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:30:26    11/9/15 14:31:07    3   11/9/15 14:31:08
363263  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:31:07    11/9/15 14:31:21    4   11/9/15 14:31:22
363264  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:31:21    11/9/15 14:31:42    5   11/9/15 14:31:43
363265  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:31:42    11/9/15 14:32:06    6   11/9/15 14:32:07
363267  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:32:06    11/9/15 14:32:44    5   11/9/15 14:32:44
363268  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:32:44    11/9/15 14:32:58    4   11/9/15 14:32:59
363269  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:32:58    11/9/15 14:33:43    5   11/9/15 14:33:45
363271  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:33:43    11/9/15 14:34:36    4   11/9/15 14:34:38
363273  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:34:36    11/9/15 14:35:17    3   11/9/15 14:35:18
363274  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:35:17    11/9/15 14:35:21    2   11/9/15 14:35:22
363275  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:35:21    11/9/15 14:35:44    1   11/9/15 14:35:46
363276  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:35:44    11/9/15 14:36:30    2   11/9/15 14:36:32
363278  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:36:30    11/9/15 14:38:19    1   11/9/15 14:38:20
363284  3466233807109235583 11/9/15 14:43:03    11/9/15 14:43:58    1   11/9/15 14:43:59
363291  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 14:46:47    11/9/15 14:47:05    1   11/9/15 14:47:06
363309  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:05:32    11/9/15 15:05:57    1   11/9/15 15:05:58
363310  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:06:50    11/9/15 15:07:10    1   11/9/15 15:07:11
363311  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:08:13    11/9/15 15:08:35    1   11/9/15 15:08:35
363315  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:09:19    11/9/15 15:09:26    1   11/9/15 15:09:27
363317  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:09:26    11/9/15 15:09:40    2   11/9/15 15:09:42
363318  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:09:40    11/9/15 15:09:50    1   11/9/15 15:09:52
363320  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:10:39    11/9/15 15:11:09    1   11/9/15 15:11:11
363321  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:11:32    11/9/15 15:11:55    1   11/9/15 15:11:56
363322  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:12:40    11/9/15 15:13:26    1   11/9/15 15:13:28
363325  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:13:26    11/9/15 15:14:37    2   11/9/15 15:14:38
363326  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:14:37    11/9/15 15:14:46    1   11/9/15 15:14:47
363329  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:18:23    11/9/15 15:18:31    1   11/9/15 15:18:32
363330  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:18:31    11/9/15 15:18:44    2   11/9/15 15:18:45
363332  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:18:44    11/9/15 15:18:52    1   11/9/15 15:18:53
363334  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:19:43    11/9/15 15:19:57    1   11/9/15 15:19:58
363335  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:19:57    11/9/15 15:20:03    2   11/9/15 15:20:04
363336  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:20:03    11/9/15 15:21:03    1   11/9/15 15:21:04
363339  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:23:45    11/9/15 15:24:09    1   11/9/15 15:24:09
363342  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:25:08    11/9/15 15:25:08    1   11/9/15 15:25:10
363343  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:25:08    11/9/15 15:25:46    2   11/9/15 15:25:48
363344  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:25:46    11/9/15 15:27:02    3   11/9/15 15:27:03
363346  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:27:02    11/9/15 15:27:14    2   11/9/15 15:27:15
363347  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:27:14    11/9/15 15:27:30    1   11/9/15 15:27:31
363351  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:28:19    11/9/15 15:31:22    1   11/9/15 15:31:22
363355  3466233807211157283 11/9/15 15:32:28    11/9/15 15:33:43    1   11/9/15 15:33:44
```

Our phone system opens at 14:00:00 UTC time.  So looking at the below data from 14:00:00 we had 0 people in the queue.  Then at 14:01:36 we had one person in the queue until 14:02:01 at which point the queue was again at zero until 14:02:19.  I'm at a loss for how to account for these times it was at zero.  Anyone able to give me some direction?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a weighted sum divided by the number of seconds.  Here is an example of how to do this in SQL Server

```
select (sum(datediff(second, starttime, endtime) * queuesize) / 
        datediff(second, '14:00:00', time(endtime))
       )
from t;
```

EDIT:

You want a weighted average.  Your version assumes that the queue size has the same values for the same amount of time.  Consider data like this:

```
starttime     endtime    queuesize
14:00:01      14:00:02      1
14:00:02      01:00:00      10
```

Your answer will be something like 5.5.  The actual answer should essentially be 10.  So, use:

```
select (sum(datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) /
        datediff(second, @monday_start_datetime, @monday_end_datetime)
       )
```

Comment: Here is the final product based on your answer. `select (sum(datediff(second, starttime, endtime) * queuesize) / 
        datediff(second, @monday_start_datetime, @monday_end_datetime)
       )
from ##acdqueue`  This returned a result of `4` for me.  it should be right around 0.06.. Monday-start-time is 2015-11-09 14:00:00.000 and end time is 2015-11-10 :01:00:00.000

Comment: I just ended up doing `(sum(queuesize) / datediff(ss, @monday_start_datetime, @monday_end_datetime))`.  This gets me pretty close to the number I am looking for.  Any reason you can think of it not working?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me... I would sum up all the start times excluding the first record and then subtract from that summed amount, the sum of all the end times excluding the last record.

Start         End

14:02:23    ->  14:02:36 (9 seconds)

14:02:45    ->  14:03:23 (7 seconds)

14:03:30    ->  14:03:36 (9 seconds)

14:03:45    ->  14:03:50

If you sum these times and subtract the two numbers

42:09:20 - 42:08:95

420920 - 420895... add in the leading zeroes

00:00:25 seconds

Comment: I'm trying to get the average queue size however.  It should be around 0.06.  1 would mean on average we have a single call in the queue.  0.06 would mean for the entire day we had 6% of a call in queue (so roughly we rarely had someone in queue for the day).

Comment: I can do it manually, which is add a 0 for every second we didn't have anyone in queue but can't seem to figure out how to do this with code in sql.